# Onclick of tabs the entire page gets selected

Tags: javascript

Any one can help me sort out this issue ?? Whenever i click on tab below like performance, Daywatch the entire page gets selected. Seems like this issue is intermittent and taking a snapshot is difficult.Apologies.. Kindly ignore.

[image: Onclick of tabs]

Comment: Where's your code? could you provide an example fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

you can use CSS to make everything you want non-selectable:

```
-moz-user-select: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none; /* From IE10 only */
user-select: none; /* Not valid CSS yet, as of July 2012 */
```

hope it's what you want!

Comment: That helped :). Thanks @Sdghasemi. Its something to do while rendering the webpage in chrome.